# How do you shutdown or restart a Windows computer over a Remote Desktop connection?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, reboot, remote-shutdown

When I connect to my Windows 7 desktop computer via Remote Desktop (MSTSC.exe), the options under the Start Menu are "Log Off" (the default), "Lock", and "Disconnect". How do I restart (or shutdown)?

Comment: r u an admin on the workstation?

Comment: Yes, I am an admin.

Comment: for your reference, I've added the normal method to do this as an anser.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I enable reboot in Windows 7 for Remote Desktop sessions?](http://superuser.com/questions/377243/how-do-i-enable-reboot-in-windows-7-for-remote-desktop-sessions)

Comment: @PeterMortensen that question is a duplicate of this one (this one was posted *two years before that one*!).

Comment: The other one is specifically about adding the option to the Start menu (vs. `shutdown /r`).

Comment: +1 for asking.  using Windows 10 ... for me, KyleMit's technique, below, is the cleanest.

Answer (score 152, accepted):

Open a command window (or <kbd>Windows Key</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>) and type the following...

...to restart:

```
shutdown /r /t 0
```

...to shutdown:

```
shutdown /s /t 0
```

Comment: /r does a reboot /t sets the number of seconds. if you want to shutdown without rebooting and turn the computer off as well use an /s

Comment: be careful of /s somebody will need to be local to powerup the workstation!

Comment: Unless you have Wake-On-Lan functionality.

Comment: This answer would probably have a lot more upvotes if everyone who did wasn't immediately logged off.

Comment: Just doesn't work

Comment: @dolphonebubleine ... Windows 10 ...  KyleMit's technique, below, is a more normal log off if that is your preference ... first one sees "Restarting..." which eventually disappears.

Comment: @tonyrroth yes.. i can not call my RDP after this. Seems like I need local guy :(  it was win server 2012. Far awaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaay from my me

Comment: C:\Users\USER>shutdown /r /t 0
'shutdown' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 71):

The answer [Marcus Adams](https://superuser.com/users/33420/marcus-adams) gave also has a keyboard shortcut: <kbd>**Ctrl**</kbd>+<kbd>**Alt**</kbd>+<kbd>**End**</kbd>. You do have to be in full screen and/or have the RDP session set to **Apply Windows key combinations** on the remote computer. This effectively sends a <kbd>**Ctrl**</kbd>+<kbd>**Alt**</kbd>+<kbd>**Del**</kbd> to the remote computer (so it's handy to know for other occasions/uses too). From there, as Marcus said, you can get to Restart, Shutdown, etc. from the little red power button icon in the lower right corner.

Alternatively, you can click once on the Desktop (or the Taskbar) of the remote computer, then press <kbd>**Alt**</kbd>+<kbd>**F4**</kbd> and you get the old-fashioned pop-up with all the shutdown options in the drop down.

**Update:** as noted in the comments, <kbd>**Ctrl**</kbd>+<kbd>**Alt**</kbd>+<kbd>**End**</kbd> in Windows 10 only gives you the option to Disconnect. You can't Restart or Shutdown from there. I also can't find a Windows Security option in the Start Menu... But no worry, as mentioned **the** <kbd>**Alt**</kbd>+<kbd>**F4**</kbd> **method still works**, and I use that exclusively now (I remote in for work every day, and also manage multiple machines at home).

Comment: `Alt+F4` is my favorite method to do this. Gives you the option to disconnect, restart, shutdown, etc.. `Ctrl+Alt+End` doesn't work with Windows 10. Well, it works, but doesn't give you the option to restart.

Comment: Couple of notes. First, Win 10 (at least as of 20H2) will obey the CAE command as a CAD now (not sure when that changed). Second, I found myself where Windows Explorer had crashed so no taskbar (Win + R wouldn't work). CAE gave me the ability to reboot when I got stuck.

Answer (score 57):

From [Ways to shutdown/restart your computer via Remote Desktop](http://weblogs.asp.net/whaggard/Ways-to-shutdown_2F00_restart-your-computer-via-Remote-Desktop_2E00_)

> Another trick is to click on the desktop and type <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd>. This will call up the shutdown dialog, where you get the usual shutdown options like "Shut down", "Shut down without installing updates", "Restart", "Stand by", and "Hibernate".

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 14):

Start button, then Windows Security. Click the little red shutdown icon, and you'll see the "Restart" option.

You use the Windows Security option for XP and Vista also. The restart option is deliberately removed from the normal location to prevent accidents.

Comment: (depending on domain settings) this works from XP to 8. Near the Logoff option in the start menu there is the "Windows Security" item. Clicking it will open a screen or dialog similar to the one you get locally after pressing ctrl-alt-del, that is: the logoff, restart, shutdown, Task Manager, change password options etc....

Comment: Added bonus: this gives access to the Task Manager as well…

Comment: This works even when special keystrokes are being intercepted by the local machine (eg when running Citrix in a browser).

Answer (score 0):

If it is Windows **Server** but not desktop, you can issue below command:

```
sconfig
```

Then enter number

> 13) Restart Server
>   14) Shut Down Server
>   15) Exit to Command Line
>
> Enter number to select an option: